# How to write formula with function inside a function

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have something like this:

```
=J1!C1
=J2!C1
=J3!C1
```

and trying to automatice....

```
=J&(ROW()-5)!C1 or =J(ROW()-5)!C1
```

but don't work, any other idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`INDIRECT`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/indirect-function-HP010062413.aspx) Function.

`=INDIRECT("J"&ROW()-5&"!C1")`